# Поиск тега, если есть хотя бы один не пустой атрибут

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Работаю с регуляркой и решаю такую задачу. В строке текста найти все теги (целые) в которых:

- тег может иметь несколько атрибутов,
- тег хотя бы с одним не пустым атрибутом `<style attr=" " attr2 = "val">` должен находиться
- вокруг знака = может быть сколько угодно пробелов, равно как между открывающими и закрывающими скобками `<  style attr  =  " " attr2  = "val"  >`
- атрибут может быть разделен дефисом или подчеркиванием `<  style attr  =  " " data-attr2-value  = "val"  >`
- свойство атрибута может содержать апостроф

Почти все работает как надо, но есть небольшая проблемка

У меня имеется следующий пример для поиска:

```
var str = '<style> > test < <styler> < = " " >\
<style test=" "> <   style stype1 =  " 1 " stype2 = ""   stype3 = ""  >\
<   style stype1 =  "  " stype2 = " 1 "   stype3 = "  "  >\
<styles data-whis-key-typetype= " Jack Daniel\'s"  >\
<styles attr =  " a1 " class =  " s d " > \
<style attr = " "> bla bla bla <style attr = ">';
```

Моя регулярка собрана по таким соображениям

```
var reg = /<[\w-_|\s+]*=\s+(["'])(?!\s+\1).*?\1(?=\s+>|>)(\s+>|>)/ig;
```

- открывающая скобка и любой алфавитный символ, дефис, подчеркивание или пробел, затем знак равно (`=`), затем еще пробелы, затем следует какая-либо кавычка и после нее сразу НЕ должна идти кавычка (с пробелами или без) - т.е. пустое свойство атрибута, затем любое кол-во символов и закрывающая кавычка и условие что дальше только закрывающая скобка > с пробелами или без (а так как благодаря условию (`?=`) сама закрывающая скобка не входит в результат поиска то я дальше просто повторил выражение только без условия (`\s+>|>)`).

Для примера выше регулярка выдает правильно, но есть одно НО

```
<   style stype1 =  " 1 " stype2 = ""   stype3 = ""  >
<styles data-whis-key-typetype= " Jack Daniel's"  >
<styles attr =  " a1 " class =  " s d " >
```

Собственно ВОПРОС:
Как видно из результата регулярка находит первый тег даже если остальные атрибуты пустые, достаточно одного не пустого.
НО если сделать первый атрибут пустым, а например второй не пустым

```
<   style stype1 =  "  " stype2 = " 1 "   stype3 = ""  >
```

то регулярка его не найдет.

Как правильно задать условие поиска (повторяющееся) если хотя бы один атрибут не пустой?

Подскажите в какую сторону копать? Пробовал подставить `{1,}` чтоб хотя бы 1 раз присутствовал тег с одним не пустым свойством, но либо не туда подставляю либо не то вообще делаю и нужен другой подход. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\<\s*\w+(\s+[\w-]+\s*=\s*\"\s*\")*\s+[\w-]+\s*=\s*\"\s*[\w\d\']+.*?\"(\s+[\w-]+\s*=\s*\".*?\"\s*)*\s*\>
```

Где:

- `\<\s*\w+` - начало тега с именем
- `(\s+[\w-]+\s*=\s*\"\s*\")*` - возможно наличие пустых атрибутов
- `\s+[\w-]+\s*=\s*\"\s*[\w\d\']+.*?\"` - один не пустой атрибут
- `(\s+[\w-]+\s*=\s*\".*?\"\s*)*` - произвольное число любых атрибутов
- `\s*\>` - закрытие тега

По атрибутам:

```
\s+[\w-]+\s*=\s*\"\s*[\w\d\']+.*?\"
```

- `\s+` - все атрибуты начинаются хотя бы с одного пробела
- `[\w-]+` - имя содержит хотя бы одну букву и/или дефис
- `\s*=\s*` - после имени идет знак `=`, быть может, обрамленный пробелами
- `\"\s*` - значение начинается с символа `"`, за ним могут идти пробелы
- `[\w\d\']+` - значение должно содержать хотя бы одну букву и/или цифру и/или апостроф
- `.*?\"` а также любые другие символы до конца значения

Пример на [RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/w8JQsl/1)

Comment: спасибо большое и самое главное за подробное описание. Благодарю